# Problem 3-40 in "Calculus on Manifolds" by Spivak. Show that we can write $g=g_n\circ\cdots\circ g_1$ if and only if $g'(x)$ is a diagonal matrix.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, problem-solving, chain-rule

I am reading "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.

> Problem 3-40. If $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\det g'(x)\neq 0$, prove that in some open set containing $x$ we can write $g=T\circ g_n\circ\cdots\circ g_1$, where $g_i$ is of the form $g_i(x)=(x^1,\dots,f_i(x),\dots,x^n)$, and $T$ is a linear transformation. Show that we can write $g=g_n\circ\cdots\circ g_1$ if and only if $g'(x)$ is a diagonal matrix.

---

We can write $g=T\circ g_n\circ\cdots\circ g_1$, where $g_i$ is of the form $g_i(x)=(x^1,\dots,f_i(x),\dots,x^n)$, and $T$ is a linear transformation.

About this part of Problem 3-40, please see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3110973/1226161).

---

Show that we can write $g=g_n\circ\cdots\circ g_1$ if and only if $g'(x)$ is a diagonal matrix.

I could not solve this part of Problem 3-40.

My attempt:

Suppose
$$g'(x)=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & 0   & \cdots & 0\\
0   & a_2 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & a_n
\end{pmatrix}.$$

We can write $g=Dg(x)\circ g_n\circ\cdots\circ g_1$, where $g_i$ is of the form $g_i(x)=(x^1,\dots,f_i(x),\dots,x^n)$. (please see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3110973/1226161).)

$g=h_n\circ\cdots\circ h_1$, where $h_i$ is of the form $h_i(x)=(x^1,\dots,a_if_i(x),\dots,x^n)$

Suppose we can write $g=g_n\circ\cdots\circ g_1$, where $g_i$ is of the form $g_i(x)=(x^1,\dots,f_i(x),\dots,x^n)$.

I want to show that $g'(x)$ is a diagonal matrix.